# Removing special characters from a string in Python

Tags: python

I have Text like this string in Python.

How do I remove the ↑ in Python.

I've tried most methods proposed by google but none seem to work.

```
Lorem Ipsum
                    ↑



        The results really show what a poisonous
```

Comment: can you post your code, what you have tried?

Comment: Did you explicitly mean the arrow char only or any special character? There's a conflict between the title and the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `str.replace()`?

```
>>> s = '''Lorem Ipsum
                    ↑



        The results really show what a poisonous'''
>>> s = s.replace('↑', '')
>>> print(s)
Lorem Ipsum




        The results really show what a poisonous
```

That works in the interpreter. If your code is in a file then you can declare the file encoding of your .py file by placing this line at the top:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I think the missing bit for me was specifying the encoding type.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
s = '''Lorem Ipsum
                    ↑
        The results really show what a poisonous'''
clean_string = "".join([ch for ch in s if ch.isalnum() or ch in string.punctuation or ch.isspace()])
```

this will remove all non punctuation/alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you show here contains the unicode character U+2191. But you forgot to say whether it was a unicode string or a byte string and in the latter case what is the charset.

If it is a unicode string (Python 3 string or Python 2 unicode):

```
s.replace(u'\u2191', u'')
```

does the trick, whatever is your Python version or charset.

if it is a byte string (Python 2 string or Python 3 bytes)

```
s.replace(u'\u2191'.encode(charset), b'')
```

does the trick provided you know what charset you use.

I always prefere this kind of input for non ascii characters, because the charset used to read Python source may not be the charset used when the program is run (that what the `# -*- coding= ... -*-` line is meant for)

Answer (score -1):

I use this script in python for replacing and removing characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#Script for replacing characters on plain text file

original = open('input.txt', 'r')
final = open('output.txt',"w")

diccionario = [
("perros", "gatos"), 
("↑", "")
]

data = original.read()
original.close()
salida = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), diccionario, data)
final.write(salida)
final.close()
```

In this example, I am replacing the word "perros" for "gatos" and removing the ↑ symbol, be sure that the file you are replacing is saved in **UTF-8 codification**.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure if you want to retain only words and numbers, so in case you just need all the special chars gone whenever one appears, I would suggest something like this which identifies any special char and not just the one:

```
import re
txt = 'Lorem Ipsum ^ The results really show what a poisonous'
for x in filter(str.strip, re.findall("[^\w.]+", txt)):
   txt = txt.replace(x,' ')
   print(txt)
```

Comment: OP did explicitly ask how to remove the ↑ character.

Comment: You're right and in that sense the question has been answered (I've upvoted the respective answer). However the subject was "Removing special characters from a string", so I thought I'd give a broader answer as well just in case.